# Eclipse C++ On Ubuntu installation Process

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am now working on a data transfer project under Linux.

The Project Team choose putty to login in linux server via vim to development, But I think the efficiency is too low.

Now I choose Eclipse for C++, and distributor the version "`eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk.tar.gz`" on  **Ubuntu**.

However, I encountered a problem: My Linux system should install **`jre1_5_0_09linuxi586`**, but I can not find it on web.

Can anybody help me on how to install Elipse for C++ on a cleanup linux OS?
What I need is Eclipse for C++ running gdb and compiling on IDE, thanks!

Comment: what distributive do you have?

Comment: @parsifal Initially unable to include more than one link in my answer so saved the detailed info with links as a private blogpost. Now I'm able to include more links so moved the detailed answer here for any other readers to access directly.  
If you feel it solves your problem you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand, but if I'm reading it correctly, you're trying to install the Java Runtime Environment and Eclipse Helios for C++ on Ubuntu.

The easiest way to install the JRE is to use the packages in the "partner" repository:

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
sudo -e /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You should see a few lines that end with the word "partner."  Remove the hash marks from the front of each of these lines.

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

Now update your package list and install the Sun Java Runtime:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

Then you can unzip the Eclipse tarball and run the eclipse binary from inside the tarball:

```
tar -zxf eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk.tar.gz
./eclipse
```

Comment: Much more detailed answer than mine, +1.

Comment: thanks ,Meyer, It sounds a good solution. But when I type "sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre" system echo below:Package  sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate.

Comment: @parsifal, what version of Ubuntu are you using?  You didn't indicate so I assumed 10.04 Lucid, since that's the most recent.  You can also use `apt-cache search '^sun-java'` to list all available Sun Java packages for your distribution.

Comment: Hi Meyer, i use  Ubuntu 10.04 LTS -the Lucid Lynx.

Comment: and I have already installed openjdk,thanks all the same: )one of the problem is my cache is not large enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- download a JRE or JDK version [on the Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) or use the process "[How to Install Java Runtime Environment (JRE) in Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-java-runtime-environment-jre-in-ubuntu.html)"
- Follow for instance those [installation instruction](http://wiki.tekkotsu.org/index.php/Eclipse_install_instructions)
- use the **[right `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659)** to launch your eclpise

Answer (score 1):

Download page of Eclipse Helios (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages) gives 2 good alternatives for C++ developers on Linux:

A) [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, 87 MB without LinuxTools](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliosr)
B) [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Linux Developers, 120 MB with inbuilt LinuxTools like valgrind, gprof, systemtap etc.](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-linux-developers-includes-incubating-components/heliosr)
C) [Installing/Updating LinuxTools using UpdateManager](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/PluginInstallHelp)  (Note: You may need to do a Java6 JRE update as described below first.)
D) [Updating Eclipse Helios CDT with UpdateManager](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/helios)
E) [Helios Installation how-to](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-helios/index.html)
F) Java6 JRE update:
    `apt-get install sun-java6-jre`
G) Unzip the Eclipse tarball and run the eclipse binary from inside the tarball:
    `tar -zxf eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk.tar.gz && ./eclipse`
For related info click [here](http://techtalkies.blogspot.com/2010/09/howto-install-eclipse-cdt-for-c.html)

Comment: thanks, friend, I also down from office Eclipse. My linux has no jave envioroment, So when I enter ./eclipse ,system resposes with "a jre must be available before available before running eclipse"

Comment: You may need to do a Java (6) JRE update before you run eclipse.
apt-get install sun-java6-jre. From your comment to Nick Meyer I understand that you have a problem doing this however. You can alternately try using the System->Synaptic Package Manager. I'm able to download the jre6 using this as the download repository: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu